# Django Comet/Long Pollling application

Tags: django, comet, long-polling

I am working a real-time lighting control system.

User can turn on/off lights through web interface, but when another person turn on/off light switch manually the web interface should be updated immediately. That's the real-time goal I want.

The structure of the system is like this.
I have my own server at home, which control/monitor light status real-time. Django project is on my cloud server communicating with my home server real-time.

I have searched some similar posts and found many tools that confuse me a lot. All I want is to do long polling. User's browser will send http request to django server periodically(say 30s). If nothing comes up, server will hold the response until next one come. If there is an event, server will just reply immediately so real-time change at the browser side.

I know websocket is a better way, but I just want to make it work, the simpler the better. As long as it's reliable, compatible with existing browsers, performance is not a primary concern for me now. I can change it later if there is performance issue when scaling up. If it's possible, I still want to use Apache server to do this.

Does anyone knows a good tutorial or example that shows me how to implement it?

Thanks so much

I use Django 1.4, wsgi, Apache.

Comment: offtopic: you should have a look at tornado.

Comment: I guess it could be possible with time.sleep(). As well as tornado you could go for a websocket solution.